# Update excel values via c# .net, allow excel to calculate the value

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop

I have an excel spreadsheet that performs complex calculations. I am injecting a value into excel using c#, and then extracting the new value of the calculations in c# also. The problem is the calculation does not happen unless i manually open the excel file and save it.

> for example if cell A1 = 1, A2=3 A4=sum(A1+A2)
>   after updating A1 = 5 via c# the value of A4 is still 4 instead of 8

Is it possible to get the excel file to update without manually opening it? I am currently using EPPplus as interop cannot be run on azure.

Any help would be appreciated even if it's just telling me it's not possible.

Comment: Possibly a stupid question; have you seen the wiki page on [GitHub](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Formula-Calculation)?

Comment: You can try to write the formula in A4 cell. By writing the formula i.e  'workSheet.Range["A4"] = "=SUM(A1+A2)"' , it will take the whatever the value is in cell and update the A4 value accordingly.

Comment: Not stupid at all AranDG, thanks for the suggestion. I had missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Spreadsheet Gear.  Works great in a server environment as well.

EDIT: The alternative is to use Automation, but I generally advise against it.  Too often you end up with memory leaks and crashes.